# Qt Creator Disable push button when precessed

Tags: qt

I'm new using Qt and I'm having some troubles with it.

I'm doing a simple terminal application and I need to disable the buttons for a few seconds after they are selected.

I'm doing something like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_readcard_clicked(){

this->setEnabled(false);

//Send Command
QString commandString = "";

commandString.append('1');
commandString.append("\n");

QByteArray commandArray = commandString.toLocal8Bit();

serial->write(commandArray);

//Read Card
QByteArray data = serial->readLine(12);

QString dataString = 0;
dataString.append(data);
ui->cardnumber->setText(dataString);
dataString.clear();
data.clear();

QByteArray saldo = serial->readAll();

QString saldoString = 0;
saldoString.append(saldo);
ui->balance->setText(saldoString);
saldoString.clear();
saldo.clear();

this->setEnabled(true);}
```

I need this because if someone press the button twice before it finished processing the first tap I will get a "crazy" array with lots of trash.
I also tried use "waitForBytesWritten" and "waitForReadyRead" but it hasn't blocked the connection until everything was processed.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try with QTimer::SingleShot() :

```
this->setEnabled(false);
QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, SLOT(enableMyButton()));
// you code
void enableMyButton()
{
    this->setEnabled(true);
}
```

It'll enable the button 2secs after the call

Comment: I tried that but still happening the same thing. If I press 2 times the button it will execute the function 2 times, and I want to "block" the button after first tap until a few seconds have passed (to confirm that everything was received).

Comment: @JoseRafael wait. what's the name of your button ?